# How to re-adjust content while resizing gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, gnome-terminal

Some times when I am compiling a script the parameters are so long that they cover many lines in the terminal. When I resize the terminal in order to read more clearly, the content does not automatically re-adjust to the size of the terminal.

Is there a way of telling the terminal to re-format its output depending on the window size of the terminal emulator?

I am using gnome-terminal, Fedora 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The content has already been sent to the terminal, so there is no longer anyone that can control it other than the terminal. And if the terminal is not written to control it, then it won't.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know any emulator that is able to do it? A work colleague mentioned that the default terminal in mac OS is able to do it so I reckon there must be something similar in linux

Comment: I usually stick to Terminal and gnome-terminal. You may want to try asking on SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome-terminal supports this feature beginning with VTE library version 0.36.

Comment: Installed v 3.10.2 and text doesn't automatically reformat accordingly to the window geometry.

Comment: What's your vte version? Check with `echo $VTE_VERSION`. Should report at least 3600. Could you please also describe in detail what you are exactly doing in the terminal?

Comment: Ok, I seem to have an older version of VTE (3409). Basically any readjusment of the text based to the dimensions of the terminal window,.

Comment: You could try to install vte-0.36.x (but not 0.38 or newer, there'd be a compatibility issue there). You might find an RPM from a newer Fedora, or compile and install manually (./configure --prefix=/usr; make; make install). Just make sure before you proceed that you're confident enough to revert the changes (e.g. you're able to remove the newly installed files and reinstall 0.34.9 from Fedora 16's RPM from an xterm window), in the unlikely case that you break the system. 34.9 and 36.x are compatible with each other, upgrading should go smoothly.